# Java Datatypes to Swift and vice versa

Tags: java, objective-c, swift

I developed a backend using Java  but i am developing a iPhone at the moment using swift but I have a question

I have Java object that includes these values

```
private List<Likes> likes;
private Timestamp date;
```

And a trying to make a corresponding object in swift like this

```
var date:NSDate?
var likes:List<Likes>?
```

But i am unsure how to translate a timestamp and a list of a object type likes has anyone every did anything similar to this ?

Comment: Don't put the type system of your programming language on the wire.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Timestamp is `java.sql.Timestamp` class.To represent a timestamp in Swift check out

```
var timestamp : NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

In Swift you can define classes and list of classes the same way just using Swift specific syntax and iOS specific APIs. For `java.util.List` use an generic `Array<Likes>`. More information can be found in the [Swift Standard Library Referenc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html).